# How to improve model loss and accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently using a Unet model taken from the kaggle starter code, and modified a couple of parameters to train it on the TACO Dataset for litter. Right now, I'm at a loss as to how I should proceed with optimizing my model. I'm experiencing ridiculous amounts of loss and abysmal accuracy, and I'm not entirely sure which parameters would improve my model's accuracy and loss. The TACO dataset has 60 categories (61 including background). Am I doing something wrong? I'm pretty new to this so any references I could read or advice would be much appreciated.

Here is the code for my model:

```
IMG_WIDTH = 224
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_CHANNELS = 3
epochs = 25
validation_steps = val_size
steps_per_epoch = train_size

##Creating the model

initializer = "he_normal"

###Building U-Net Model

##Input Layer
inputs = Input((IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS))

##Converting inputs to float
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

##Contraction
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c5)

##Expansion
u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c9)

##Output Layer
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(61, activation="softmax")(c9)

##Defining Model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])

##Compiling Model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

##Training the model
results = model.fit(x = train_gen, 
                    validation_data = val_gen, 
                    steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch, 
                    validation_steps = validation_steps, 
                    epochs = epochs, 
                    verbose = True)
```

And here is the accuracy and loss from the first epoch:

```
Epoch 1/25
 185/1200 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3:30:04 - loss: 388.0077 - accuracy: 9.0721e-04
```

I'm currently using tensorboard, modelcheckpoint, and earlystopping for callbacks, but unfortunately I don't know how these will help with optimizing my model. Would a larger number of neurons per layer work?

Comment: What about loss value at other epochs?

Comment: It's still training right now at 791/1200, and its loss value is at 386.2904. Is there nothing wrong with my model, though? And can I expect the loss to go down to a manageable value after a few epochs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are not happy with training speed: `ETA 3:30:04`. Usually models should train a few epochs to get significant reduction of  loss. But waiting 4 hours per epoch isn't cool, is it? There is several things you can do:

- Make sure that you train your model on GPU, because the difference between training on CPU and GPU is insane
- You can try make you model less complicated
- Or, if you want to have complicated model, but you don't have much time to train, use Transfer Learning

In transfer learning you can use pretrained model, add your own layers and retrain. Here's an example:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

base_model = MobileNetV2(
    include_top=False, 
    input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS)
)
base_model.trainable = False

layer = Dense(256, activation='relu')(base_model.output)
layer = BatchNormalization()(layer)
out = Dense(61, activation='softmax')(layer)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=out)
```

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like a nice method. I'm using google colab right now, and I'm also wondering if getting those loss and accuracy values in the first epoch are normal.

Comment: 1 epoch is not enough to draw conclusions. But yes, there is a chance that your model is not learning. Try to do things that I written above - that should deffinetely impove the speed. If the loss won't change after several epochs, try to build another model. Also, if you see an answer that helped you, please mark it as correct

Comment: Although changing to google colab's GPU  didn't really change the training time, I found a fix by changing the starting amount of neurons to 32, and scaling everything else. I also changed the loss function to 'sprase_categorical_crossentropy', which helped probably because I had a lot of categories, I wasn't exactly one-hot encoding my input. Here are my loss and accuracy values for the first epoch: Epoch 1/25
   5/1200 [..............................] - ETA: 4:55:12 - loss: 3.2374 - accuracy: 0.6040   Regardless, I think I'll be able to use your code on transfer learning. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Yoshutik's answers.
Actually, you should train the models like yours on the GPU. Because your image dataset contains 3-channels images with size of 225*225, the computation amount is tremendously large. You can reduce number of channels to 1.
Speaking of structure of your model, you could eliminate at least 3 convolution layers by considering input-output relationship.
One more thing is, you can manipulate hyperparameter of optimizer without using default value.
here is code:

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0076), loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['mse'])

Actually, I am not sure about the accuracy supported by Tensorflow, thus you should change metrics into others.

Comment: This is a classification problem, so setting `metrics=['mse']` is just plain wrong. It's not at all clear what you mean in your last sentence - TF of course does support accuracy. Reducing the channels to 1 is a shallow advice.